# Yoast-like real-time content analysis

Tags: plugins, plugin-sproutseo, seo, plugin-seomatic

Is there an equivalent to `Yoast's` real-time content analysis for Craft?

I've looked at `SEOmatic` and `Sprout`, but neither of them have the handy traffic light system that `Yoast` has on WP (despite both are looking to be great for everything else SEO related).

I'm trying to get my company to switch from WP to Craft (for the bigger projects at least), but my director considers the traffic light check-list to be an important time saver for non-techies/clients to post quality content.

This feature will clinch the deal! Help me Craft Stack Exchange Kenobi, your my only(ish) hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the [SEOmetrics Content Analysis](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic/wiki/06.-SEOmetrics-Content-Analysis)? There's a video of it in action on that page too.

I'm currently working on SEOmatic for Craft 3; let me know what this "traffic light" does, and I can have a look at doing it!

Comment: Honestly - this is better than what Yoast provides. Much more in depth yet simpler to use (much like the rest of the plugin). I feel like a bit of a fool not noticing this feature was available. I've yet to get into the nitty-gritty of using this plugin but I'm impressed by what I've seen and I look forward to using it. Cheers!

Comment: Glad it's something that will be useful to you!

Answer (score 1):

Since Craft is mainly build for developers why don't you create your own plugin? From my experience Craft is a time saver all over the place and when you compare the time you need to build a complex non blog site with Craft and WP - Craft will win for sure unless you are going to build sites for less than 100$ with existing themes without writing a single line of code.

I don't know Yoast and I don't really know other SEO Plugins because we made a private real time analysis tool for our customers but I know even when we consider the time we spend for this plugin, all our sites consume less time and effort with Craft than with WP. With the experience I collected within the last 3 Years I can say it's not worth to use this CMS if you are going to solve every problem with an existing plugin like for WP.

[Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html) + [Craft3](https://github.com/craftcms/docs) have awesome and very powerful tools to extend the system however you like. There are so many great features and opportunities to customize nearly every aspect of the system within a really short amount of time and effort without loosing much performance or risk security issues. Due to it's well considered API you can create complex frontend logic really fast with plugins and [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html) modules.

If your director think the initial time loss is not worth it or if your company does not has the developers you need to create such a plugin it's not a good idea to move to Craft in the first place (at least that's my opinion) because as I said there are not that much plugins for Craft as there are for WP since it's so easy to solve problems and the group of customers is usually totally different

Edit:
within a quick search: maybe [webtexttool](https://www.webtexttool.com/) is something you want?https://github.com/iNalgiev/webtexttool

Comment: I agree entirely with everything here. I managed to covert him without the plugin, but that webtexttool looks like just the thing if he begins to miss it. Thanks!